# VBA SHELL COMMAND not executing

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I am novice to VBA shell. So i request an explanation to understand how things work.
Through EXCEL VBA, I would like to create a *.bat file and execute the same automatically. However my command lines ONLY creates the file and does not execute it. Please suggest.

```
Sub Create_Motor_Model()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

CURRENT_SHEET = "Script"
Output_path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

InputData1 = Cells(1, 2)

file_output = Output_path & "\" & "Input.bat"
    Open file_output For Output As #1
        Print #1, Chr(34) & InputData1 & Chr(34) & " -b -i " & CURRENT_SHEET & ".mac -o Output.out"
    Close #1
    
Shell ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Input.bat"

End Sub
```

Comment: please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function  It shows you how to use `Shell()`

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner for the swift response. I will look into the shared link and let you know.

Comment: Also ensure that you have the right to execute a bat file from the output path. In some corporate environments, it is forbidden to execute that kind of files if they are not from within program files.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, I tired with different options however it does not run on its own. I had to execute the *.bat file manually every time.